# Need to hide transition when app enters from background to foreground in iphone

Tags: objective-c

I am having two controllers like

firstController and secondController

When am in firstController am clicking on home button its going to background state,

but, when am again enters to foreground i need to show secondController instead of firstController.

For that I am implementing code in forground to navigate to secondController its navigating but first its showing firstController and then its showing secondController I need to avoid that how to do am not getting.

Please anyone help me to solve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,

Sai.

Answer (score 0):

When your app goes to the background, iOS takes a screen shot of it's state. Therefore when you push your controller at the `didEnterBackground` stage, it won't make a difference at next activation whether you pushed another controller or not - the screenshot of second controller will be shown regardless.

Now, the good practice is to hide sensitive information when the app **resigns active** in the `willResignActive` app delegate. You could also try pushing your secondController when the app resigns active but then you will need to keep track of whether it ever went to the background or not and push the firstController when app becomes active again (in case it never went to the background)

Hope this explanation makes sense